# Register Host Function: "runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: env:ext_storage_proof_size_storage_proof_size_version_1"

Tags: host-functions

When upgrading my node to the latest version of the Polkadot-SDK, I get the following error when trying to run the node:

```
Error:           Error: Command failed with exit code 1: bash -c ./target/release/parachain-template-node export-genesis-head -d /var/folders/_1/q03733qd0pv42n1dvkcvyx0c0000gn/T/zombie-a62cc984247da3304e3610859e23df97_-39473-pjQiul72IZpH/export-genesis-state/2000 --chain /var/folders/_1/q03733qd0pv42n1dvkcvyx0c0000gn/T/zombie-a62cc984247da3304e3610859e23df97_-39473-pjQiul72IZpH/2000-rococo-local.json /var/folders/_1/q03733qd0pv42n1dvkcvyx0c0000gn/T/zombie-a62cc984247da3304e3610859e23df97_-39473-pjQiul72IZpH/cfg/genesis-state-2000 && ./target/release/parachain-template-node export-genesis-wasm --chain /var/folders/_1/q03733qd0pv42n1dvkcvyx0c0000gn/T/zombie-a62cc984247da3304e3610859e23df97_-39473-pjQiul72IZpH/2000-rococo-local.json /var/folders/_1/q03733qd0pv42n1dvkcvyx0c0000gn/T/zombie-a62cc984247da3304e3610859e23df97_-39473-pjQiul72IZpH/cfg/genesis-wasm-2000
Error: Service(Client(VersionInvalid("Other error happened while constructing the runtime: runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_storage_proof_size_storage_proof_size_version_1'")))
2024-03-26 13:31:38 Cannot create a runtime error=Other("runtime requires function imports which are not present on the host: 'env:ext_storage_proof_size_storage_proof_size_version_1'")
```

How do I register / add the `storage_proof_size` host function?

Answer (score 2):

Your host functions are registered in the `service.rs` file of your node.

Here is the relevant code in the latest version of the Polkadot SDK (as of writing this post):

```rust
#[cfg(not(feature = "runtime-benchmarks"))]
type HostFunctions =
    (sp_io::SubstrateHostFunctions, cumulus_client_service::storage_proof_size::HostFunctions);

#[cfg(feature = "runtime-benchmarks")]
type HostFunctions = (
    sp_io::SubstrateHostFunctions,
    cumulus_client_service::storage_proof_size::HostFunctions,
    frame_benchmarking::benchmarking::HostFunctions,
);

type ParachainClient<RuntimeApi> = TFullClient<Block, RuntimeApi, WasmExecutor<HostFunctions>>;
```

You can see the `HostFunctions` type includes the `cumulus_client_service::storage_proof_size::HostFunctions` which is what you need to fix that error.

Once your `ParachainClient` is configured with the right `HostFunctions`, the error should go away.